# change property in oData entry when posting. [WCF dataservice + EF + SQL express]

Tags: javascript, wcf, entity-framework, odata

I have a simple set up WCF data service + EF + SQL Express DB.
I consume this oData in a mobile app which is written in javascript.
Also this is my first time dealing with WCF and EF stuff so I dont know much.

I need to add a record to db but for one of the columns i need to provide a value from System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString().

I guess I cant do it on the application side when I am constructing an oData entry to post.

So can I achieve this in WCF? For example when I post an entry to db, WCF intercepts and adds System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString() value to the property of the entry?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WCF Data Service ChangeInterceptor for this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd744842(v=vs.100).aspx